# How do I delay selecting from a dropdown until it's populated?

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir WebDriver. I'm new to ruby.

The following dropdown list is always present. It fails unless I precede it by sleep(1). The developer said that the dropdown is not populated until the previous controls are set.

Which of the Wait commands do I need for this? I think in Selenium I waited until the hidden contents of the list contained the value that I wanted, then I selected that value.

```
def enterCompany(company)
    @browser.select_list(:id, "ddlCompanyName").select(company)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `when_present` to wait until the option is present before selecting it. Basically, Watir will wait up to 30 seconds for the option to appear. If it appears sooner than 30 seconds it will proceed with the action (ie select). Otherwise, a timeout exception is thrown.

```
@browser.select_list(:id, "ddlCompanyName").option(:text => company).when_present.select
```

Note that the above assumes that `company` is the text of the option.

Another option is to wait for anything to appear in the dropdown.

```
@browser.wait_until{  @browser.select_list(:id, "ddlCompanyName").options.length > 0 }
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked fine, even after removing sleep(1).

The second method failed with error. For my own education, I'll experiment in IRB.

Answer (score 1):

A question was just asked of me offline on this one, so I wanted to provide an updated answer for the latest Watir versions that avoids the deprecated `#when_present` method:

```
browser.select_list(id: 'ddlCompanyName').wait_until { |el| el.include? company }.select
```